# Finding Natural Domain of functions and expressing answer in terms of intervals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

Really have no clue on how to do this. Some of the questions I have are

> (a) $f(x)=2x^2$

> (b) $f(x)=x^8$

> (c) $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}-7$

My attempt was for the answer for the first one was(−∞,∞) because it stood for all the real numbers.
Would this be the same for $x^8$? And how do I go about the third question? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The natural domain of a function is the set of all inputs it can accept. It does not include any inputs that'll make the particular function undefined.

1. The domain of $x^2$ is $\mathbb{R}$, or $(-\infty,+\infty)$ as you rightly mentioned. $x^2$ is a function which
   can accept anything, but returns only real numbers, starting from $0$.
2. The domain of $x^8$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $(-\infty,+\infty)$.What makes you think it'll be
   anything else?
3. $\frac{1}{x}-7$ would consist of all real numbers, excluding zero. As you may know , $\frac{1}{0} $ is not defined, hence zero will not belong to the domain. So, we can write the domain as $(-\infty,+\infty)$ - {$0$}